# How to use custom Schema & Sproc Prefix in ELMAH script

Tags: .net, sql-server, web-config, elmah

I am using ELmah Exception logger, I run the script in my database with my custom schema

```
 Create Table [myschema].[ELMAH_Error] //instead [dbo]
 ...........
 ...........

 CREATE PROCEDURE [myschema].[ELMAH_GetErrorXml] //instead [dbo]
 ...........
 ...........
```

This is not working for me. Is it I need to do additional configuration to apply the same, please help me on this.

Comment: Have you create schema with name [myschema] before using instead of dbo if not create it IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT schema_name 
    FROM information_schema.schemata 
    WHERE schema_name = 'newSchemaName' )
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE SCHEMA NewSchemaName;';
END

Comment: yes.. I have created, Elmah unable to identify with custom schema because elmah configured with 'dbo'